# How to get the right value for the jquery "id" variable in this custom code?

Tags: jquery

I have 20 divs with the same class (bio):

```
<div class="bio" data-id="<? echo $id; ?>">
  <p>the bio1 text</p>
  <a id="car" href="http://www.mycustomurl.com">my car 1</a>
</div>

<div class="bio" data-id="<? echo $id; ?>">
  <p>the bio2 text</p>
  <a id="car" href="http://www.mycustomurl.com">my car 2</a>
</div>

--------

<div class="bio" data-id="<? echo $id; ?>">
  <p>the bio20 text</p>
  <a id="car" href="http://www.mycustomurl.com">my car 20</a>
</div>
```

I make this ajax call when someone clicks the link with the id **car**:

```
jQuery("#car").click(function(){
    var id = $(".bio").data('id'); /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM, id is always empty */
    jQuery.ajax({  
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'myajaxurl',  
    data: {  
       action: 'cars',
       id: id
    }
        });  
});
```

**The problem is:**

How do I get the right **id value** (var id) corresponding to the right link that was clicked?

Do I need a jquery each loop?

It does not seem to work, **var id** is always empty.

Comment: ID should be unique and should not be duplicated.

Comment: The id coming from php is unique <? echo $id; ?>

Comment: Is it because you don't have `=` signs in what should be `class="bio"`?

Comment: Juhana, its not that, just a typo, i'll edit

Comment: `data-id` doesn't have to be unique, but you shouldn't have multiple elements with `id="car"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `closest`.

```
var id = $(this).closest(".bio").data('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

As in:

```
jQuery("#car").click(function(){
 var id = $(this).parent(".bio").data("id"); /* Maybe this should even be .data("data-id") ? */
 jquery.ajax({ /* etc... */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique and should not be duplicated.

Instead trying binding your handler like below,

```
jQuery('.bio a').click( function(){
   var id = $(this).parent().data('id');
   //..
```

When you do `jQuery("#car").click(function () {`, it is going to bind the handler to the first matching element with ID `car` which is going to be just for the first div group.